# How to require value for certain column in Grails/GORM mapping?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a grails application which works with a legacy database.

I have in almost all tables a column, let's say `include`. I want to include such entities in query results if and only if this column has a nonzero value.

Is there any way for specifying this on a per class / application criteria in grails, perhaps in a static mappings block? Currently I'm I specifying `AND include == 1` whenever I make a database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) will get you what you need.